# Android In-app Billing Issues

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I am using this tutorial:

http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/.

When I get to the last step:

```
 checkout.sendCheckoutRequest(purchaseUri.toString(),null);
```

it crashes. What is the `purchaseUri` for?

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the blog with the latest as per changes from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This purchaseUri is the “In-app Product ID” of your resource on the “market.android.com/publish->Create New In-App Product” options. This string should be set as the “in app product” id. That’s why the “id” is most important. The “In-App Product ID” is how you refer to that particular product.
Also, in Security.java dont forget to add your “public key” from your market place account “edit profile” page.

Comment: Found the answer a while ago, but thanks! It was the correct answer.